# Check-out/in files on TFS via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'd like to use PowerShell to automate check-out and check-in of edited .csproj files to TFS.  I only need to change single files to pending and check those in.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same pain you are having, and finally got to the right way of doing so.
Here you go.

```
#Load the TFS powershell
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
# the filePath should be in the format like C:\MyFodler\MyFile.txt
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $filepath -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -wa 0
# Check in the file after changes.
New-TfsChangeset -Item $filepath -Verbose -Comment "Comment Here" -Override true
```

Answer (score 7):

You can checkin with the `New-TfsChangeSet` cmdlet and checkout with the `Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit` cmdlet.

To get the cmdlets you have to have the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools installed.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for that cmdlet? I've installed the Power Tools and updated PowerGUI and they're not appearing at the moment.

Comment: @StuperUser: Using Bing I found https://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/10/01/preview-of-the-next-tfs-power-tools-release.aspx?Redirected=true and https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/team-foundation-powershell-pssnapin-in-october-team-foundation-power-tools-drop/

Comment: To make the cmdlets available in a PowerShell session or script, you have to first add the snap-in to the environment: `add-pssnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`.