# search my aspx files and delete

Tags: c#

what's the best way to read all my aspx files in a directory, search for HeaderText="Variable Text" and delete it and save the file?

Also, is there a way to programmatically check the file out of tfs at the same time it is being updated?

Comment: Do a Replace in Files in VS2010? (shortcut ctrl+shift+h)

Comment: find /path/to/root -name *.aspx -exec /bin/bash -c 'mv {} {}.tmp && sed "{s/HeaderText=\"Variable Text\"//}" < {}.tmp > {} && rm {}.tmp' \; (Yes, this is a joke!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a powershell script to do it, and you could also checkout files from tfs

[Check-out/in files on TFS via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470871/check-out-in-files-on-tfs-via-powershell)

this would be a fine exercise!!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as rene says, but in answer form: Replace in Files in Visual Studio will do the trick, including checking out files if needed and keeping them open in case you want to undo.

You can use Regular Expressions if you want, too.

Comment: you know of any beginner resources for regular expression?